# put the block at the end without absolute position

Tags: html, css

I have a block that on the desktop version should have an absolute position, and for the mobile version it needs to be replaced so that all elements do not interfere with each other

```css
.wrapper {
    position: relative;
    border: 2px solid black;
    border-radius: 10px;
    padding: 20px 0 0 20px;
    height: 250px;
}

.text {
    max-width: 300px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.button {
    width: 50px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    border-radius: 10px;
    cursor: pointer;
    padding: 10px 15px;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
}

.block {
    position: absolute;
    width: 200px;
    background: purple;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
    z-index: 2;
    padding: 10px 15px;
 }
 
 @media only screen and (max-width: 767px) {
  .block-wrapper {
       display: flex;
       justify-content: flex-end;
  }
  
  .block {
      position: relative;
  }
 }
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</div>
  <div class="button">Button</div>
  <div class="block-wrapper">
    <div class="block">
      <div class="block-name">Hector</div>
      <div class="block-position">Developer</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

If there will always be position: absolute for the block, then with large text and a small screen, this block will intersect with the button

Therefore, for the sizes of small screens, I need to make the elements go one after another

I made the display flex to align this block to the right, but how can I make it always be at the end of the whole wrapper?

Comment: You have a set height of 250px on the `wrapper` element. Remove that `height` or change to `auto` on mobile

Comment: @wouch 
the height is just the point, I can have several such wrappers, and they will have the same height, depending on the content, I specifically inserted this height into the example to make it clear

Answer (score 0):

Add this inside your media query `@media only screen and (max-width: 767px)`.

```css
.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
```